# Can we connect a normal earphone / headphone to a Android device?

Tags: hardware, headphone-jack, compatibility

Can we connect a normal earphone / headphone (those that we connect to the Desktop PC) to the Android phone or devices?

This is because I notice that the one on the left (the original one that come with the phone) have 4 connector but the one we use on Desktop PC have 3 connector.

Was wondering if it will short-circuit and damage the phone or the port itself.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The typical audio only jack has 3 rings, usually call Tip, Ring, Sleeve (**TRS**). These typically map to *Left*, *Right*, and *Ground*. Phone manufactures wanted to make this jack work with existing headphone so they used a connector with 4 rings, called Tip, Ring, Ring, Sleeve (**TRRS**). These map to *Left*, *Right*, and *Ground* just like the 3 ring, but the final connector maps to a *microphone*. This makes it so that if you plug an audio only cable into it, **the microphone input gets connected to ground so nothing is hurt**. It also means that if a headset with microphone is connected to an audio only device, the microphone is connected to ground, also hurting nothing.

[image: TRS (Stereo) Jack Plug]
[image: TRRS (Quad / 4 Pole) Jack Plug]

Sources:

- [What protocol does a headphone jack use?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12498/what-protocol-does-a-headphone-jack-use)
- [Leads Direct: Jack Plugs & Sockets](http://www.leadsdirect.co.uk/technical/jacks.html)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, a "regular" set of headphones will work just fine, in much the same way that a single-channel earphone works in a stereo headphone jack. The other bits are for the microphone and the controls, but since your headphones won't have those it won't matter.

I have had occasion to use 1st generation iPod earbuds as well as some generic earbuds in my Galaxy Nexus. My daughter uses a pair of headphones I had lying around (that are probably ten years old) in her phone when she's at home listening to music. At *worst* you may find a channel doesn't work (no sound in one ear) but you don't need to worry about shorting out or damaging anything.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29#Mobile_phones) has more information than you could possibly want to know about 3.5mm connectors.